# Android Add text view in table row

Tags: android, android-layout

Ok I have declared my main.xml as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/AdMob"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/AdMob" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablelayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/banner" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/start_message"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/start"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Start Now" >
            </Button>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my main activity is

```
package com.michaelpeerman.demotivational_posters;

import com.michaelpeerman.demotivational_posters.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView start_message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.start_message);
    start_message.setText(Html.fromHtml("Thank you for downloading \"Demotivational Posters\" \n Click start below to start. \n To advance to the next picture click the \"Next\" button. \n If you see an image you would like to download click the \"Download\" button. \n If you enjoy this app please leave a rating."));
}
}
```

When i go to compile my program it force closes automatically. The logcat output is

```
03-13 01:59:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(14336): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 01:59:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(14336): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.michaelpeerman.demotivational_posters/com.michaelpeerman.demotivational_posters.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TableRow cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
03-13 01:59:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
03-13 01:59:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-13 01:59:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-13 01:59:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-13 01:59:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-13 01:59:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-13 01:59:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-13 01:59:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 01:59:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-13 01:59:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-13 01:59:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-13 01:59:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-13 01:59:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(14336): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TableRow cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
03-13 01:59:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at com.michaelpeerman.demotivational_posters.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
03-13 01:59:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-13 01:59:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-13 01:59:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-13 01:59:50.240: E/AndroidRuntime(14336):    ... 11 more
```

I can not figure out what it means that i casted the tablerow to textview

Comment: this line android:layout_below="@id/AdMob" >

Comment: What about that line? its just laying out the scroll view below the relativeview inside a relative view whats wrong with that?

Comment: I tried the code you paste here..its working fine..what I am assuming is you that you have a name conflict ...e.x. when you give the same id to two different widgets or views..check you xml once for duplicate ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clean and rebuild your project once again. If that is not working then close your project and open once again refresh the project and run. I tried with your given code. It is working in my case.

Comment: Thank you. It is working once again. Ill keep that in mind for now on.